# Repeat loop in r until the values in one column are less than several other columns

Tags: r, loops, while-loop, repeat

I have a data set `df` where the last column (`value`) consists of sampled values. In the same data set I have several other columns (`rep1:rep4`) whose values need to be less than the sampled value in the same row. If this criteria isn't met, I need to resample the the `value` column and try again. This needs to be repeated until the numbers in `rep1:rep4` are less than corresponding number in the `value` column.

I'm still trying to get a handle on loops, but it seems that a `while` loop might be what to use here.

```
    ID  rep1  rep2  rep3  rep4  value
1   a   NA    NA    NA    NA    -400
2   b   -400  NA    NA    NA    -300
3   c   -400  -300  NA    NA    -200
4   d   -400  -300  -200  NA    -300
5   e   -400  -300  -200  -300  -400
6   f   NA    NA    NA    NA    -400
7   g   -400  NA    NA    NA    -400
8   h   NA    NA    NA    NA    -400
9   i   NA    NA    NA    NA    -200
10  j   -200  -300  NA    NA    -300
11  k   -300  NA    NA    NA    -200
12  l   NA    NA    NA    NA    -300
13  m   NA    NA    NA    NA    -300
```

```
structure(list(ID = structure(1:13, .Label = c("a", "b", "c", 
"d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m"), class = "factor"), 
    rep1 = c(NA, -400L, -400L, -400L, -400L, NA, -400L, NA, NA, 
    -200L, -300L, NA, NA), rep2 = c(NA, NA, -300L, -300L, -300L, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, -300L, NA, NA, NA), rep3 = c(NA, NA, NA, 
    -200L, -200L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), rep4 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, -300L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), value = c(-400L, 
    -300L, -200L, -300L, -400L, -400L, -400L, -400L, -200L, -300L, 
    -200L, -300L, -300L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-13L))
```

This is the start of what I have:

```
while(df$value < df$rep1:df$rep4) { repeat sampling process }
```

The sampling process is a multiple step procedure which I can include if necessary, but might overly complicate things. From my limited understanding of loops, if I follow `while` with conditions that *do not* meet my intended results, it will continue the loop (in my case resampling) until the time when the resampled data in every row of the `value` column are greater than the values in columns `rep1` to `rep4`.

This brought up several errors (no surprise): an NA/NaN argument, and several errors stating that despite the numerical expressions of df$rep1:df$rep4 having multiple elements, only the first was used.

For the NA/NaN argument, I am guessing that the issue is that not all rows of the rep columns are filled, making it impossible to compare values with those in the `value` column. For the issue of only the first element being used, I'm not sure if that is because the NA/Nan broke things, so it couldn't continue, or if the code needs to specify that all rows are checked.

The intended output for this is the dataframe itself. If it passes the loop requirements, the dataframe will be valid and I can continue forward with that data.

Comment: without a reproducible sample is difficult to provide a complete answer, but maybe you could try `while(df$value < any(df$rep1:df$rep4),na.rm=T)`, you also need to clarify how you want to deal with NAs especially when all values rep1:rep4 are NAs in a single row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose 
1) we ignore NAs in the calculations
2) The sampling process is to add 100 when the value is not the highest value

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  while (any(df$value[i]<=as.numeric(df[i,2:5])%>%na.omit())){
    df$value[i]=df$value[i]+100} #Here you should replace with your sampling process
}

> df
   ID rep1 rep2 rep3 rep4 value
1   a   NA   NA   NA   NA  -400
2   b -400   NA   NA   NA  -300
3   c -400 -300   NA   NA  -200
4   d -400 -300 -200   NA  -100
5   e -400 -300 -200 -300  -100
6   f   NA   NA   NA   NA  -400
7   g -400   NA   NA   NA  -300
8   h   NA   NA   NA   NA  -400
9   i   NA   NA   NA   NA  -200
10  j -200 -300   NA   NA  -100
11  k -300   NA   NA   NA  -200
12  l   NA   NA   NA   NA  -300
13  m   NA   NA   NA   NA  -300
```

Comment: This works perfectly. I initially hadn't thought about how NA's should be treated, but for my purposes, ignoring them is a better approach than treating them as 0's. Since there is the possibility of data either being positive or negative, converting NA's to 0's would throw off the analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you are treating NA as 0s.

```
df[is.na(df)]<-0
while(any(df[,2]:df[,5]) > df[,6]){
  df[,6]<-sample(df[,6])
}
```

Comment: I hadn't thought about whether the NA's should be treated as 0's or omitted. In my case, because there is the possibility of using positive and negative numbers, treating NA's as 0's would throw off the calculations. I appreciate the option you provided though.